# How can I send data with PHP to an IP address via UDP?

Tags: php, udp, sockets

How can I send data with PHP to an IP address via UDP?

How can I recive that data on the other computer?

```
<?php
$fp = pfsockopen( "udp://192.168.1.6", 9601, $errno, $errstr );

if (!$fp)
{
    echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
}
socket_set_timeout ($fp, 10);

$write = fwrite( $fp, "kik" );
//$data .= fread($fp,9600);
//echo "$data<br>";
fclose($fp);
echo "<br>Connection closed ..<br>";

if (!$write) {
    echo "error writing to port: 9600.<br/>";
    next;
?>
```

This code sends the "kik" with a program I can read it on the another computer, but how can I see it in the browser?

Comment: Viktor, please re-post your second question as a different question.

Answer (score 9):

My PHP knowledge is a bit rusty so I've been doing some searching trying to find some good guides and tutorials. This one [PHP Sockets Made Easy](http://www.litfuel.net/tutorials/sockets/sockets.php)looks like it will be a good starter guide for you.

**Edit**: The original article I posted did not go into great detail for UDP so I eliminated the previous code. The article from the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php) has some more information specifically regarding UDP:

```
<?php
$socket = stream_socket_server("udp://127.0.0.1:1113", $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND);
if (!$socket) {
    die("$errstr ($errno)");
}

do {
    $pkt = stream_socket_recvfrom($socket, 1, 0, $peer);
    echo "$peer\n";
    stream_socket_sendto($socket, date("D M j H:i:s Y\r\n"), 0, $peer);
} while ($pkt !== false);

?>
```

**Edit #2**: Here is another [useful tutorial](http://www.weberdev.com/ViewArticle/Socket-Programming-With-PHP) for socket programming in PHP. It is mostly TCP but it does include a section on how to alter the code to use UDP instead.

Comment: Adam Davis: Thanks for that. I'll keep doing some more eyeballing. I know the article above talks -some- about UDP.

Comment: Aw, this is a way better answer than mine.  I'm all jealous and huffy now.

Answer (score 1):

Just pulled this snippet out of some working code I have

```
if (!socket_bind($sh, LISTENIP, LISTENPORT)) exit("Could not bind to socket");

while (TRUE) {
    // $z = socket_recvfrom($sh, $data, 65535, 0, $connectip, $connectPort);
    while(socket_recvfrom($sh, $data, 65535, 0, $connectip, $connectPort)) {
        $pid = pcntl_fork();
        if ($pid == -1) {
            die('could not fork');
        } else { #START ELSE COULD FORK
            $PIDS[$pid] = $pid; //KEEP TRACK OF SPAWNED PIDS
            if ($pid) {
                //PARENT THREAD : $ch is a copy that we don't need in this thread
            } else {
                /** CHILD THREAD::BEGIN PROCESSING THE CONNECTION HERE!    **/
                include "include/child_thread.inc.php";
            } //Child Thread
        }//if-else-forked

        /** CLEANUP THE CHILD PIDs HERE :: "Any system resources used by the child are freed." **/
        foreach ($PIDS as $pid) pcntl_waitpid($pid,$status,WNOHANG);

        $i++; //INCREASE CONNECTION COUNTER
    }//While socket_accept


    /** CLEANUP THE PARENT PIDS **/
    foreach ($PIDS as $pid) {
        $returnPid = pcntl_waitpid($pid,$status);
        unset($PIDS[$pid]);
    }
}//While True
```

Comment: oops, forget to include a send portion (this is the easy part)

  socket_sendto($sh,$packet,strlen($packet), 0x100,$connectip,$dest_port)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that the [PHP's socket reference](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sockets.php) is a good place to study on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$server_ip   = '127.0.0.1';
$server_port = 43278;
$beat_period = 5;
$message     = 'PyHB';
print "Sending heartbeat to IP $server_ip, port $server_port\n";
print "press Ctrl-C to stop\n";
if ($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP)) {
  while (1) {
    socket_sendto($socket, $message, strlen($message), 0, $server_ip, $server_port);
    print "Time: " . date("%r") . "\n";
    sleep($beat_period);
  }
} else {
  print("can't create socket\n");
}
?>
```